# Will IFTTT applets using Instagram keep working with the upcoming Instagram API deprecation?

Tags: if-this-then-that, instagram

Sadly Instagram is going on with deprecating their API.

After December 11, 2018 it will not be possible anymore to display an Instagram feed (latest 20 posts) on a website. (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/)

Will [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/discover) applets using instagram still work after the deprecation?

I could not find any information about it and IFTTT does not mention the deprecation at all (except https://ifttt.com/blog/2016/05/a-change-in-how-instagram-works-with-ifttt).